# Mapping multiple Tables with similar column structure

Tags: java, ejb

I have an EJB which I want to use for two tables. These two tables have identical columns except for a few additional columns in one of the tables. How can I use the @Table annotation provided by javax.persistence.Table to get it done. I do not wish to remap the columns using @secondaryTable because they have identical names. Let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood well, you need the [@MappedSuperclass](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqn.html#bnbqp) annotation.

I am copying the examples from [here](http://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/MappedSuperclass).

1. Create the super class that will contain the common columns that both tables feature :

   ```
   @MappedSuperclass
   public class GenericCommonTable {

       private String address;

       public Address getAddress() { ... }
       public void setAddress(Address addr) { ... }
   }
   ```
2. Add the 2 concrete tables that share the same columns :

   ```
   @Entity
   public class ConcreteTableOne extends GenericCommonTable {

      //your xtra columns here
   }

   @Entity
   public class ConcreteTableTwo extends GenericCommonTable {

      //your xtra-columns here
   }
   ```

Hope that helps